# StreamBuilder not work when enter to the page again

Tags: flutter

First thanks in advance, i try to create an app and i triyng to use flutter with it, first i managed the user's state login inside an app and for that i take this guide https://fireship.io/lessons/flutter-firebase-google-oauth-firestore/ the app work as i expected with facebook login in the login page (the observable emits a new values and with the StreamBuilder create the corresponding widget everything ok!), but when i press return button to other page and enter to the login page again, the stream associated to StreamBuilder widget return null thus shows again formLogin (form to register) widget instead profile widget (widget to show user's info) or maybe i use wrong the streamBuilder any advice is well recieved.

i put the code

and again thanks in advance

**Login Widget (widget for manage login and user's info) and AuthService (logic for login)**

```
  ProfilePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  _ProfilePageState createState() => _ProfilePageState();
}

class _ProfilePageState extends State<ProfilePage>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  var opacity = true;
  AnimationController _controller;
  Animation<double> _animation;
  bool _loading = false;
  final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKeyLogin = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKeyLogup = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final PageController _pageController = PageController();
  int _typeForm = 0;
  // int currentPage = 1;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _controller = AnimationController(
        vsync: this, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 1500));

    _animation = CurvedAnimation(
      parent: _controller,
      curve: Curves.decelerate,
    );

    _controller.forward();

    authService.loading.listen((state) => setState(() => _loading = state));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            StreamBuilder(
              stream: authService.profile,              
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  User user = User.mapFromMap(snapshot.data);
                  return new FormProfile(loading: _loading, user: user);
                } else {
                  return new FormLogin(
                      animation: _animation,
                      loading: _loading,
                      pageController: _pageController,
                      formKeyLogin: _formKeyLogin,
                      formKeyLogup: _formKeyLogup);
                }
              },
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}




    class AuthService {
  final GoogleSignIn _googleAuth = GoogleSignIn();
  final FirebaseAuth _firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  final Firestore _firestore = Firestore.instance;
  bool isAdmin = false;

  Observable<FirebaseUser> user; //FirebaseUser instance
  Observable<Map<String, dynamic>> profile; //database's user info
  PublishSubject loading = PublishSubject();

  AuthService() {
    user = Observable(_firebaseAuth.onAuthStateChanged);
    profile = user.switchMap((FirebaseUser u) {
      if (u != null) {
        return _firestore
            .collection("users")
            .document(u.uid)
            .snapshots()
            .map((snap) => snap.data);
      } else {
        return Observable.just(null);
      }
    });
  }

  Future<FirebaseUser> facebookLogin() async {
    loading.add(true);
    final facebookLogin = FacebookLogin();
    final result = await facebookLogin.logInWithReadPermissions(['email']);
    FirebaseUser user;
    switch (result.status) {
      case FacebookLoginStatus.loggedIn:
        final AuthCredential credential = FacebookAuthProvider.getCredential(
            accessToken: result.accessToken.token);
        try {
          user = await _firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential);
          await validateAccount(user);
          updateUserData(user);
        } on PlatformException catch (e) {
          switch (e.code) {
            case Strings.AUTH_CONST_ERROR_INVALID_CREDENTIAL:
              Utilities.showToast(
                  Strings.AUTH_CONST_ERROR_INVALID_CREDENTIAL_MSG,
                  Toast.LENGTH_LONG,
                  2);
              break;
            case Strings.AUTH_CONST_ERROR_USER_DISABLED:
              Utilities.showToast(Strings.AUTH_CONST_ERROR_USER_DISABLED_MSG,
                  Toast.LENGTH_LONG, 2);
              break;
            case Strings
                .AUTH_CONST_ERROR_ACCOUNT_EXISTS_WITH_DIFFERENT_CREDENTIAL:
              Utilities.showToast(
                  Strings
                      .AUTH_CONST_ERROR_ACCOUNT_EXISTS_WITH_DIFFERENT_CREDENTIAL_MSG,
                  Toast.LENGTH_LONG,
                  2);
              break;
            case Strings.AUTH_CONST_ERROR_OPERATION_NOT_ALLOWED:
              Utilities.showToast(
                  Strings.AUTH_CONST_ERROR_OPERATION_NOT_ALLOWED_MSG,
                  Toast.LENGTH_LONG,
                  2);
              break;
            case Strings.AUTH_CONST_ERROR_INVALID_ACTION_CODE:
              Utilities.showToast(
                  Strings.AUTH_CONST_ERROR_INVALID_ACTION_CODE_MSG,
                  Toast.LENGTH_LONG,
                  2);
              break;
            default:
              Utilities.showToast(Strings.AUTH_CONST_ERROR_GENERAL_CODE_MSG,
                  Toast.LENGTH_LONG, 2);
          }
        }
        break;
      case FacebookLoginStatus.cancelledByUser:
        break;
      case FacebookLoginStatus.error:
        Utilities.showToast(result.errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT, 2);
        //_showErrorOnUI(result.errorMessage);
        break;
    }

    loading.add(false);
    return user;
  }


final AuthService authService = AuthService();
```

Comment: If you need to reload Stream then you would need to call that in to initState, this link could help you  - https://inducesmile.com/google-flutter/how-to-reload-or-refresh-a-flutter-streambuilder/

Answer (score 1):

Your issue may stem from the fact that you're using Observables rather than Streams, or in the case of your loading object, a PublishSubject. As documented here for the [rxdart Observable class](https://pub.dev/documentation/rxdart/latest/rx/Observable-class.html), Observables are single-subscription - and by your description you have already received data from this subscription somewhere else in your app.

Consider using a broadcast stream (Observable asBroadcastStream) which is multi-subscription, another PublishSubject (which is inherently a broadcast), or if you're not married to using Observables in particular, you could replace them with the standard Dart Streams, in which case your interfaces could look like something below:

```
BehaviorSubject<FirebaseUser> _user; //Or PublishSubject
Sink<Map<String, dynamic>> get inProfile => _user.sink; // call .add() to inProfile to add new data
Stream<Map<String, dynamic>> get outProfile => _user.stream; // attach this to your Streambuilder output
```

Comment: Hi Sean, validate the code in the main page i validate and exists other subscription `authService.profile
        .listen((data) => {_isSignIn = (data != null) ? true : false});` if i delete that line it works i will try change the class of the Observable for multiple subscription of profile (this is the observable cause of the problem and not user for more information) Thanks i will validate